# Unable to resolve IP Blacklisting with Spamhaus

Tags: email, email-server, spam, ip-address, blacklist

I have a website which is currently assigned an IP 64.XXX etc from my hosting provider. This IP when looked up comes up clean with all Blacklist checks that I run. However, I am also being assigned an IP 108.XXX etc (which I am assuming is my dynamic IP) from my current ISP. This 108.XXX IP is showing as being listed with Spamhaus when checked for blacklisting with MX toolbox and Spamhaus directly. It is not showing as being listed with Anti-abuse.org.

When trying to resolve the situation with Spamhaus directly, I get the following message:

```
The IP address removal process failed for the following reason:

The netblock owner's policy does not allow removal from the PBL
```

I am planning on setting up a new website under a new domain with a different hosting provider and I am also planning on moving in the next few months which will likely put me with a new Internet Service Provider.

My question is, would setting up the new domain and site now and transferring to a new ISP in a few months remove me from any blacklistings when the new ISP change takes place? or will setting it up now have the blacklisting follow the domain reputation to the new ISP? or are there any suggestions on action that could be taken now?

Answer (score 3):

Removal of dynamic IP addresses from the Spamhaus blocklist is not desirable.  The RFCs support such blocking, and these blocks allow a lot of spam to be blocked.   Spamhaus documentation covers this blocking set.  I commend your ISP on providing their dynamic IP addresses to Spamhaus and putting a block on their removal.

Properly configured mail servers need a static IP address with DNS configured to pass reverse DNS validation.  Hosts with a dynamic address should use an assigned relay server to send email.

I am curious as to what your issue with a web server being blocked from sending email.  In general, web servers don't sent email.  If you are sending email from your web server, use a properly configured mail server.  This can be running on the same host as you web server, but is an entirely different service.